# Variant of words for John

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

Is it possible to specify a mask (of sorts) on the command like with John the Ripper where most of the words are known (but not the permutations used in the passphrase)?

Example: If part of the passphrase is the word "Agile", the passphrase could be one of "aGile", "Ag!le", "Ag1le", etc.

I know one the command like I could specify a mask such as:

`--mask='?a' --min-length=xx --max-length=yy`

But I know that the passphrase uses a few words and is 12-20 characters long (so just doing the above mask will take a very long time to compute given the number of ASCII characters that will be tried by default. I can reduce that by at least seeding the phrase with a couple of possible words (that may require some minor substitution) and let John deal with any prefix and postfix words or special characters (e.g. trailing "!" characters, etc.)

Comment: welcome - do any of these answer your q? https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjohn-the-ripper%5D+mask

Comment: Not specifically but I figured out an approach that will work (generated a wordlist with a large number of variants for specific placeholder characters that may differ ... e.g., "iI1") and then ran (still running :) ) JtR with a set of custom rules (e.g., something like: 'cA0"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]"Az"[!]"Az"[!]"') for prefix/postfix possibilities.  I'm sure there could be a more efficient method but this is just a background job on another machine that will run for a long time